# Set img src from Byte Array

Tags: java, javascript, html, image, jsp

I need to set the `img src` property from a byte array that I have in a Object.

```
<img id="profileImage">
    <spring:bind path="object.profilePicture">
        <input type="file" name="profilePicture" id="profilePicture" path="profilePicture">
    </spring:bind>
```

I need to display that byte array in the `img` above the input tag.

Comment: Do you have a specific question? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. SO is not for code writing requests or open-ended advice.

Comment: I would need to know how to display a byte array in a img tag, from an object that I have

Comment: You cannot just generate an image from a byte[]. You need to know what type of image (ie jpg, png, gif) it is as well

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Replace the `jpg` with the type of image, and  `[your byte array]` with your `byte array`. You need to convert it to `base64` if it isn't already.

```
<img id="profileImage" src="data:image/jpg;base64, [your byte array]">
```

Comment: how do I convert to 64? is there a data type in javascript?

Answer (score 5):

In my case the base64 byte array had to be chunked, in the way:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/4QCARXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgABAEaAAUAAAABAAAAPgEbAAUA
AAABAAAARgEoAAMAAAABAAIAAIdpAAQAAAABAAAATgAAAAAAAABIAAAAAQAAAEgAAAABAAOQAAAH
...
```

To make this solution works.

Answer (score -1):

I use this site to convert images to the `base64` byte array data, it gives me the tags in `html` and `css` so I just upload  and copy/paste.

http://base64.wutils.com/encoding-online/