# How to convert ByteBuffer to Image in HTML

Tags: javascript, java, html

I convert the image to bytebuffer in java and send it through websocket in java to client.
Java side look like :

```
@OnOpen
public void onOpen(Session sessions) {
    String fileName = sessions.getUserPrincipal().getName() + ".png";
    File fi = new File("/Users/shilu/MyProject/Chat/Photo/" + fileName);
    byte[] fileContent = null;
    try {
        fileContent = Files.readAllBytes(fi.toPath());
        ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(fileContent);
        sessions.getBasicRemote().sendBinary(buf);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In client side I just get it like this :

```
gp.onmessage = function(evt) {
    var msg = evt.data;
};
```

Now how do I display that image in html...?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set img src from Byte Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30129486/set-img-src-from-byte-array)

Comment: How to convert evt to byte array??

Answer (score 0):

Try to put evt.data into image src attribute

```
gp.onmessage = function(evt) {
   var msg = evt.data;
   document.getElementById("image").src = msg;
};
```

Comment: This will not work, it need to be converted to data URI for it to work.

Comment: How to convert it to data URL

Answer (score 0):

First you need to convert the data to base64 and then create data URI:

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = 'data:image/jpg;base64,' + btoa(evt.data);
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

Comment: No, it is not working I get error as TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById("#profImg").src = 'data:image/jpg;base64,' + btoa(evt.data)')

Comment: @R.Shilesh remove hash from `#profImg`, `getElementById` accept id not css selector for id.

Comment: can u tell how to change the source of an already created element.

Comment: this should work: `document.getElementById("profImg").src = 'data:image/jpg;base64,' + btoa(evt.data)`

Answer (score 0):

converts your image bytes to base64 encoded string in java before returning.

`StringUtils.newStringUtf8(Base64.encodeBase64(buf.array(), false));`

then add image in your html file as below:
`<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,{base64String returned from java}"/>`