# How to Convert byte[] to Uri Image

Tags: android, image, sqlite, uri

I save the image uri by using below code

```
 public void insert (Uri image) throws SQLiteException {
        SQLiteDatabase database = mdb.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        try {
            InputStream iStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(image);
            byte[] inputData = com.example.tony.monthlyexpenses.Utils.getBytes(iStream);
            cv.put(MyDatabaseHelper.KEY_IMAGE,inputData);
        }catch(IOException ioe)
        {
            Log.e("A", "<saveImageInDB> Error : " + ioe.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        database.insert(MyDatabaseHelper.TABLE_EXPENSES, null, cv);
        database.close();
    }
```

**Utils**

```
    public static Bitmap getImage(byte[] image) {
            return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
        }

 public static byte[] getBytes(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int bufferSize = 1024;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        int len = 0;
        while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        return byteBuffer.toByteArray();
    }
```

Now I want to retrieve the image and display as setImage `Uri` instead of setImage 'Bitmap'.

```
 byte[] bb = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex("ImageReceipt"));
 imageView.setImageBitmap(Utils.getImage(bb));
```

Comment: If it is the same as the web then maybe this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30129486/set-img-src-from-byte-array/30130095#30130095

Comment: you have an `Uri` when calling `insert(Uri image)`, what is that `Uri`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on the contents of the array of bytes.

Let assume that your array of bytes are URI characters, you can use the following code:

```
byte [] buf = <your byte array>;
String s = new String(buf, "UTF-8");
Uri uri = Uri.parse(s);
```

*But In your case **it's not possible** to convert image byte array to image Uri, U can save your image Uri instead of storing bitmap. so that u can read it as an image Uri and reduce memory space too.*

Comment: I get unhandled exception

Comment: @Tony please check my answer in your case it is not possible to convert image byte array to image uri.

Comment: How to save it as image uri ??

Comment: just keep your MyDatabaseHelper.KEY_IMAGE column as a TEXT or VARCHAR data type and inside your insert (Uri image) method keep like this cv.put(MyDatabaseHelper.KEY_IMAGE,image);

Comment: Thanks..Now I just realize we can put Image datatype as `String` ?

Comment: you are welcome. yes can pass uri as string to TEXT or VARCHAR data type column.