# Angular 8 - display images in the angular material's grid

Tags: angular

Title: Angular 8 - display images in the angular material's grid.

I'm trying to display images retrieved via a web ap from SQL server in the Angular material's grid.

The image in the table is stored as: 
    varbinary NOT NULL

The rows are retrieved from the table but fail at display time.

I'm getting the error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Do I have to do some conversion or something to get the images to appear in the grid?

My SQL server table definition:

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblImages]
 (  
    [ImageId]        [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ImageData]      [varbinary](max) NOT NULL
  CONSTRAINT [PK_Image] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED   
 (  
  [ImageId] ASC  
 )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
 ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]  
 ) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

My html is:

```
<!-- A list of images in a 3-column grid. -->
<div>
    <mat-grid-list cols="3" rowHeight="2:1">
        <mat-grid-tile *ngFor='let i of allImages'>
            <img [src]='i' class="tile-image">
        </mat-grid-tile>
    </mat-grid-list>
</div>
```

My Angular images model is:

```
 import { Binary } from '../../node_modules/@angular/compiler';

 export class Image {
    ImageData: Binary[];
 }
```

My Angular component is - I'm just showing the array used in the html. The rest of the code is not shown:

```
allImages: Observable<Image[]>;
```

Comment: Where is the code that makes the http call? Do you see any response in the browser developer tools network/preview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is due to the fact that the ngFor loop attempts to iterate over an observable. The async pipe might be useful :

```
<!-- A list of images in a 3-column grid. -->
<div>
    <mat-grid-list cols="3" rowHeight="2:1">
        <mat-grid-tile *ngFor='let i of allImages | async'>
            <img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,{{ i.ImageData }}' class="tile-image">
        </mat-grid-tile>
    </mat-grid-list>
</div>
```

Comment: The grid is now filled with small icons that look like a piece of paper with a bend in the upper right hand corner. I get an error in the console: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found). Does some kind of binary conversion to image need to take place first?

Comment: I've just now realized that allImages is an array of Image objects. The src property was probably fed something like "[object Object]".  I have updated the code to reflect this change.

Comment: I now get: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 431 (Request Header Fields Too Large)

Comment: I see. What are the contents of `i.ImageData` ?

Comment: I have: console.log("1st image content: " + this.allImages[0]);  It shows undefined. .....Below are the Request header, Response header and the Response.

Comment: Request header: GET /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAFhUXFRUYFRgVFRcYFR... (NOTE: the ellipses indicate the data continues. Then stops). 
Host: localhost:4200 Connection: keep-alive User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.97 Safari/537.36 Accept: image/webp,image/apng,image/*,/;q=0.8 Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin Sec-Fetch-Mode: no-cors Referer: localhost:4200 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9

Response header: 
HTTP/1.1 431 Request Header Fields Too Large Connection: close

Response: data:text/plain,

Comment: Looks like a base64-encoded payload. This issue is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30129486/set-img-src-from-byte-array). I edited the solution to take it into consideration.