# How "img" tag showing running video (very curious to know)

Tags: php, html, ws

[no response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95aSc.jpg) img tag is showing live video from my mobile camera but response is empty. So how this is getting data continiously ? I have attached a video footage of this please check that to see exact thing happening. thank you !
[img tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLyTS.png)

[video footage](https://youtu.be/tgKpiDnArq0)

Comment: Your video is private, it needs to be unlisted if you want it hidden to anyone without a link

Comment: I suspect that it might be an issue with Chrome rather than `video` having no response. It could be a mime-type issue. What type of file is `video`?

Comment: i dont know about mime type . its a mobile app name ip camera on play store that is showing live camera in img tag . i can see the page is loading infinitly while showing live camera my question is when there is no response from link how is it showing img continiously ? and sorry for private video i m changing it right now take a look please

Comment: you didn't show the head tags. might be some javascript is being executed. show the full page source

Comment: i dont have source file and i dont thing showing data from inspect mode is readable so i didnt gave full page source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but my guess is that it simply grabs a picture X times per second, saves it with name `video` and then forces `<img />`'s `src` attribute to be updated with more or less the same frequency.

What seems to be misleading here is how Chrome developer tools present information.

First of all, response tab in Chrome always says "empty" when you check an image request. I couldn't find why.
Theoretically, when a browser requests an image it is returned as byte stream. You can even [use byte stream directly in src attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30129486/set-img-src-from-byte-array). However, Chrome will somewhy hide it from you.

Another thing here is that when a page requests an asset (img/js/css or other) more than once, Chrome Dev Tools' network tab will only show 1 last request to this resource.

As I said, I don't know if I'm right or not. You can check it out by going to Chrome Developer Tools -> video -> preview. If I'm right, you will see that content in this tab is also being "streamed".

BONUS:
Actually you **can** [show a video in img tag](https://codepen.io/shshaw/pen/MOMezY)! However, as for now, it only works in last versions of Safari.

Comment: thanks for your awesome reply . Now i got it how its showing video very nice explanation .

Comment: @AmirRahman hope it helped! :) Please consider marking the answer as accepted if it resolved your issue/answered your question.