# Image not showing in angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, angular11, ng-file-upload

When I'm testing my API from postman I can view my images but from my angular application, I cannot able to view images. There is no error in the console. below is my code which I tried.

**Asp.net web API 2**

```
    [HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [Route("api/another")]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetFile(int productId)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);

            IEnumerable<ProductImage> files = _context.ProductImages.Where(p => p.ProductId == productId);
            foreach (var item in files)
            {
                response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(item.Image);
                response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = item.Image.LongLength;

                response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
                response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = item.Name;

                response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(item.ContentType);
            }
            return response;
        }
```

**HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let img of imageData">
  <img [alt]="img.Name" [src]="img.Image">
</div>
```

**component.ts**

```
 imageData: any[] = [];

  getImages() {
   this.image.getProduct().subscribe(res => {
   this.imageData = [res];
   console.log(res);
  });
 }
```

**service.ts**

```
  getProduct() {
    return this.http
      .get(this.apiUrl + 'another?' + 'productId=' + 2, {responseType: 'blob'})
      .pipe(
        retry(2),
        catchError(this.handleError),
      );
  }
```

[console.log output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLSMy.png)

Comment: The obvious question: Are you sure you're forming the full path to the image? I don't see the full route to the API path being passed to the `src` attribute.

Comment: in your API you only return an image. Yes, you made a loop, but in each loop you override the content:`response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(item.Image);` so you only get the last one image. You need create a function in the API that return the "files" and use a forkJoin to get the images (or directly use as src)

Comment: @Eliseo can u help me solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Double check your api response to see what it is returning.

You need src to be **"data:image/jpg;base64, [your byte array]"**

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64, [your byte array]">
```

[Set img src from Byte Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30129486/set-img-src-from-byte-array)

Comment: Your answer only applies to inline base-64 encoded images. There's nothing I see in the sample code that implies the API is using base-64 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use DomSanitizer to tell angular src value is safe. Take a look at this class from angular:

```
this.image= this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('data:image/jpg;base64,' 
                 + yourBase64String);
```

If you don't receive a string base64 check if the image URL is working.

Comment: can u explain how I can use this. I didn't get